# How to JOIN TABLES with WHERE clause in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, join-table

I want to join two tables, the `customer_entity`, and `customer_entity_varchar`. but I have no idea how to do it. This is my current query:

Let's assume I the `entity_id` is 5 and `attribute_id` is 139.

```
$customerCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->getSelect()->join( array('varchar'=> 'customer_entity_varchar'), 'varchar.entity_id = main_table.entity_id', array('varchar.attribute_id'))->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => '5'))->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_id',array('eq' => '139'));
```

Below is the query I want to achieve.

```
SELECT attribute_id, entity_id FROM customer_entity INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar ON customer_entity.entity_id = customer_entity_varchar.entity_id WHERE customer_entity.entity_id = 5 AND customer_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 139
```

I am stuck with this. I am using Magento 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

use this way:

```
$customer=Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$customer->getSelect()->join(array('cev' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('customer_entity_varchar')), 'cev.entity_id = e.entity_id')
->where("e.entity_id =5 AND cev.attirbute_id=139");
```

As I think you cannot use addAttributeToFilter here

Comment: Is there any way to add the AND clause to the JOIN clause so that i filter when the JOIN occurs vs after when the join occurs? this makes a big performance difference on larger tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the same and debug. you will get to know.

```
    $customerCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
    $customerCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->getSelect()->join( array('cev'=> Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('customer_entity_varchar')), 'cev.entity_id = main_table.entity_id', array('cev.attribute_id'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => '5'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_id', array('eq' => '139'));

   echo $customerCollection->getSelect(); exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define table alias in addAttributeToFilter for your query,
like, **main_table.entity_id** and **varchar.attribute_id**

```
 $customerCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->getSelect()->join( array('varchar'=> 'customer_entity_varchar'), 'varchar.entity_id = main_table.entity_id', array('varchar.attribute_id'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('main_table.entity_id', array('eq' => '5'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('varchar.attribute_id', array('eq' => '139'));
    echo $customerCollection->getSelect();
```

Comment: I got error in main_table.entity_id.